# Auditing C++ Project Dependencies in VS2008

Tags: c++, winapi, visual-studio-2008, compiler-construction, linker

I have a VS2008 C++ project and I want to get an exhaustive list of its dependencies on include files, libraries and other files, create copies of these (Windows SDK, MFC, etc) alongside the project.

My aim is:

1. To have a complete filestore package that is completely self-contained, with no external dependencies so it is clear what the total source of the project is
2. To be able to transport the whole package to another machine and rebuild it with VS2008 at the destination without any errors, regardless of whether any of the SDKs exist there.

How do I go about getting a definitive list of every single input file that my project depends on?  I'm familiar with

> Tools > Options > Projects and Solutions > VC++ Directories
>
> Project > Properties > Configuration Properties > C/C++ > General > Additional Include Directories
>
> Project > Properties > Configuration Properties > Linker > General > Additional Library Directories

but these specify only which directories are searched during compile and link, not the actual files that are used.

Are there any other build dependencies that I should be aware of, in addition to .h includes and .lib links?